# Cannot login to XP SP3 in VMWarePlayer virtual machine in safe mode

Tags: windows-xp, safe-mode, vmware-player

Here is my setup
Host OS: XP SP3
Guest OS: XP SP3 (using VMWare)

I checked the /SAFEBOOT option in System Config utility in guest for troubleshooting. Now the guest OS boots up in Safe Mode but I cannot login with my user id/password.

Here is what I tried:

- [domainName]\[userid] for user name => Login Fails
- Administrator with blank password => Login fails
- Safe Mode with Networking => Login fails
- Safe Mode with Command Prompt => Login fails
- Last Known Good Configuration => starts in safe mode, login fails
- Start Windows Normally => starts in safe mode, login fails
- Don't have cd to get to the recovery console

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. Hopefully, this will help someone else having a similar problem.

I used the following tool to reset local Admin password.

Offline NT Password & Registry Editor (http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)

1. Download the tool Extract the .iso file into a folder of your choice
2. Start your VM (VMWare Player - 2.5.4    build-246459 in my case)
3. [Set your   BIOS boot order to boot from CD](http://techpaul.wordpress.com/2007/08/03/how-to-boot-from-a-cd/)
4. In VMWare Player menu select Devices > CD/DVD(IDE) > Connect to disk image file (.iso)
5. Choose the image you extracted in step 1
6. Reboot VM
7. It should boot into the downloaded tool's command prompt menu
8. Follow the instructions to change/clear local admin password
9. Disconnect from the disk image file you connected to in step 4
10. Reboot and change BIOS options to boot from hard drive
11. Login with the local admin password